# Updating datagrid WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have created this window:
[image]

When I add a new user, delete or update, it successfully applies to server. But it doesn't update the datagrid below. Here is one of my functions :

```
private void Delete_Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using(var ctx = new PersonelContext())
    {
        PersonelEntity personel = (
            from s in ctx.Personels
                where s.Name == NameBox.Text
                select s).FirstOrDefault();
        ctx.Personels.Remove(personel);
        ctx.SaveChanges();
    }                        

    this.personelEntityDataGrid.Items.Refresh();

}
```

As you see I'm refreshing the datagrid but it still doesn't show the new results. How can I fix this?

Comment: You need to clear the itemssource and bind it again

Comment: @Sajeetharan would it be too much if I ask how to do that? :)

Comment: Why don't you use a binding on Personels and INotifyPropertyChanged with OnPropertyChanged(Personels) ?

Comment: @Antoine I'd appreciate if you give me a tutorial about it. Thanks.

Comment: There are a lot to say, and already a lot of tutoriels on the subject.

Comment: @Antoine Actually, I did this. http://codepaste.net/pgdm79 but I don't know the next step.

Comment: Mate what is the item source of your datagrid

Comment: @moez  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=.}"

Comment: Ok i will show you an exemple, wait plz.

Comment: you could set your item source from code behind mean you create an ObservableCollection<PersonelEntity> an fill it with your data a pass it as item source or you can bind it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**MVVM Exemple**

Let's say you have got a windows with a datagrid :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication7.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding Personels}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Nom" Binding="{Binding Nom}" Width="200"></DataGridTextColumn> 
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
</Window>
```

We have to define his datacontext (or the binding won't know where to find) :

```
namespace WpfApplication7
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            this.DataContext = new MainViewModel(this);
        }
    }
}
```

Then we can define the ViewModel (datacontext of the windows) :

```
class MainViewModel : ViewModelBase
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Référence de la fenêtre principale
        /// </summary>
        private MainWindow mainWindow;

        /// <summary>
        /// Liste des personels
        /// </summary>
        private ObservableCollection<Personel> personels = new ObservableCollection<Personel>();


        public ObservableCollection<Personel> Personels
        {
            get 
            {
                return personels;
            }
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Constructeur de la classe
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="mainWindow">Référence de la fenêtre principale</param>
        public MainViewModel(MainWindow mainWindow)
        {
            this.mainWindow = mainWindow;

            AddPersonel("Toto");

            AddPersonel("Jack");

            AddPersonel("Momo");

            AddPersonel("Momo");

            AddPersonel("Momo");

            AddPersonel("Momo");
        }

        private void AddPersonel(string namePersonel)
        {
            personels.Add(new Personel() { Name = namePersonel });
            OnPropertyChanged("Personels");
        }
    }

    class Personel
    {
        private string name = "NoName";

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }
    }
```

MainViewModel must implement INotifyPropertyChanged to notifies controls that a property value has changed. :

```
public abstract class ViewModelBase : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
        {
            if (this.PropertyChanged != null)
            {
                this.PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to implement first INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

Also when you delete the item from your list create a new list without that item and set it as item source to your DataGrid

```
IEnumerable<Personels> res = m_Parameters.Where( p.Name != NameBox.Text));

personelEntityDataGrid.ItemsSource = res;
```